# Read from EEPROM and print to serial

Tags: c++, arduino

I want following Arduino function to read from an EEPROM address and return a string that I can print on my serial monitor.

```
char EEPROM_read(int addr, int length_str) {
     char letter[length_str];
     for (int i=0; i<length_str; i++) {
      letter[i] = EEPROM.read(addr);
      addr ++;      
     }
     //Serial.println(letter); This works inside the function, but I need it to work outside of the function
     return letter;
    }


  serial_number = EEPROM_read(0,11);
  Serial.println(serial_number); //This does not work
  String SN(serial_number);
  Serial.println(SN); //This does not work
```

Comment: You can't do this as VLA are not allowed in C++. Additionally, you are returning a ptr to a local array `letter`which will point to something that ceases to exist upon return. Use `vector`or declare the array static and set it to a maximum length.

Comment: use EEPROM.,get https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMGet

Comment: array `letter` exists only in that function. and you even don't return it right

Comment: @doug, VLA works with gcc used with Arduino

Comment: @Juraj Yep, VLA is an extension gcc can do but isn't standard C++. But the OPs larger problem is that the local array is no longer valid when the function returns a pointer to it. It's undefined behavior. Worse, it sometimes works but will almost always change as your program proceeds and can be quite difficult to troubleshoot. The simplest approach is to declare the array static. Make in large enough to handle the max you need, and check that is the case when you use it. It's not thread safe but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return text in RAM, you need space for it in RAM. On an Arduino and in your case, dynamic memory allocation is a suboptimal idea, so you better provide that space in advance:

```
 char* EEPROM_read(int addrE, char* buf, int length_str) 
 {
   for (int i=0; i<length_str; i++) {
     buf[i] = EEPROM.read(addrE++);
     if (buf[i] == 0) break;        
   }
   return buf; 
 }

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  char text[20];
  Serial.println(
    EEPROM_read(0, text, sizeof(text))
  );
}
```

In this sample, the variable `text` is only available inside `setup`, yourself should be able to make this usable beyond the sample scope.